# What file resets fstab on persistent live environments?

Tags: live-usb, fstab, persistence

I'm trying to add lines to my `/etc/fstab` file.
but the lines I add get cleared on reboot because I am using a persistent live USB stick.

I don't want a lecture. I just want to know which file writes the `/etc/fstab` file at restart and I want to alter that file so that I can auto mount the disk I want.

So this is not really a question but more like a request.

I am requesting the location of the file/files that are responsible for writing to or resetting `/etc/fstab` on restart.

Comment: I was able to add the line "gksu mount /dev/sda2 /media/Windows" to my startup apps program and it seems to work fine but I still wish I could get fstab working.

Comment: Are you sure it is reset, and not just ignored?  I would think it would just be ignored, because the new version saved in the persistence file is not used until after the original fstab is processed.

Comment: Maybe you will have to make a customized live-usb. See this: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=59876

Comment: @psusi, nope, not ignored because when I reboot I reopen fstab and the line I entered is gone.

Comment: this is amazing that a simple file that resets the fstab can't be found O_o it has to be just a simple shell script somewhere.

Comment: or a simple .conf file or something.

Comment: I would imagine that /etc/fstab is likely not the file that is processed in a live environment because those are generally decompressed from filesystems-in-a-file. Try poking around within the mounted filesystem-file.

Comment: Rather than using a "persistant live USB" stick, why not simply install Ubuntu to the stick. All your changes will then persist.

Comment: Yeah, it could work, but I guess I'd need to use 2 usb sticks for that :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Fortunately they are inexpensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my **LiveUSB** install with Ubuntu 11.10 (which has a **casper-rw persistence loopback file**), the file that worked for me to have drives mounted automatically is:

```
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-bottom/12fstab
```

I added lines into that script which worked to add new drive mounts upon boot-up.  The odd thing is that my `/etc/fstab` file does NOT reflect the drive mounts.  This would seem to suggest that the `/etc/fstab` file is **just a dummy file** or something to the LiveCD setups.  Not sure, but **changes added to the 12fstab file DO persist**.

Comment: This seems to be outdated. Well at least it didn't work for me. I added a line to `/etc/fstab` of my live system and tested it with `sudo mount -a`. It worked. Then I added the same line at the appropriate place in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-bottom/12fstab` and rebooted. No effect. Might be that the mount point was bad or something - need to test that.

Comment: fstab confirmed still being overwritten after changing 12fstab and running update-initramfs -u. used rc.local and it worked. But now I have the issue of not being able to change my root mount properties to account for my horribly slow usb flash drive performance.

Answer (score 1):

Add your mount commands in **`/etc/rc.local`**

```bash
...
mount -t ntfs-3g -L Inter /media/Inter -o uid=1000,gid=999,umask=002
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a live media with persistence, I always simply install directly to the flash drive. This way any changes I make are kept. Whether the changes are to the data stored there or the system configuration or applications I have installed is irrelevant with this approach. If you still need the live media for installation purposes you can put a copy of the ISO on the stick and boot it as needed as outlined [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot)