# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Dell Inspiron 5537 leads to low graphics mode error

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, graphics, dell, inspiron

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron 5537, and the installation completes with no errors, but when I boot into Ubuntu I get a popup window saying:

> the system is running in low-graphics mode ... device settings could not detected correctly.

This model iscertified by Canonical!
When I choose <kbd>re-configure</kbd>, I keep getting the same window!
When I press <kbd>esc</kbd>, I get a black screen, and nothing happens.

How can I fix it?

[image: low graphics mode popup]

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be occurring because of the graphic driver. So **you must consider using proprietary graphic drivers**(i.e graphic driver provided by AMD) instead of the default open source driver. But since you are in the live USB mode(i.e in 'Try Ubuntu without installing') if you install the driver and reboot(so that the driver might work) you won't get the driver working, as(going by your question) you haven't set up any persistence. So first thing: you must set up persistence. I will explain how to do this below:

### Step 1 - Set up persistence :-

- First, **partition your USB device into two partitions** from your Windows OS. Keep at least a 1 GB or so partition for the Ubuntu installation files(make this a FAT32 partition). Make another ext4 partition of the remaining space and remember to name it `casper-rw`. Use a GParted Live CD for this purpose(or any other partitioning software you like. I am recommending this because it worked for me). I am providing a few screen shots below(but these are not of the Gparted Live CD, I used):-

---

(Creating the FAT32 partition mentioned below)
[image]

(Creating the `casper-rw`(ext4) partition)
[image]

(How it looks after partitioning)
[image]

---

- Now put the installation files into the FAT32 partition. For this you must use  [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). See the screen shot below of UNetbootin :-

[image]

Note see what all I have selected and select exactly the same in your UNetbootin too. Also compare this image with the image before it. I have selected /dev/sdb1 since that is my FAT32 partition. You should accordingly in your PC.

- Now, after the UNetbootin process is over, get into the FAT32 partition and delete the file named `casper-rw` so that Ubuntu will use the `casper-rw` partition instead of that file to store your data. It will be around 10MB (as we selected in UNetbootin).
- Now you have successfully created a live USB with persistence! Just boot in with the USB device and select 'Try ubuntu without installing'.

Now that we have created a live USB with persistence we can install AMD driver.

### Step 2 - Installing AMD driver :-

- Now when you boot in with the USB device and select "Try Ubuntu without installing" you will get "Low graphics mode error" as you have mentioned in your question. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. You will get a terminal window. From there connect to the internet.
- Now type:

`sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle`

- Now restart with:

`sudo reboot`

- Now boot again and press "Try Ubuntu without installing" and it must work properly now.

Install Ubuntu and enjoy now!!

PS :- Credits for Step 1 go to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138356/how-do-i-get-a-live-usb-to-use-a-partition-for-persistence/181062#181062) answer. Refer it for some extra info on step 1 .