# Persistence USB with External Python Libraries

Tags: python, live-usb, persistence

I have a fresh install of a Ubuntu 14.04 on a flash drive with 4GB persistence space, and I want to install easy_install, pip, ipython, and other external python libraries that can easily be accessed whenever the Live Boot version of Ubuntu is running from that USB.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I already tried to do this in general using

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip
```

as usual, but I quickly learned that any programs/libraries I installed on my persistence drive using this method were thrown away whenever I started a new session of the Live Boot.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled persistence?

Comment: I followed these instructions and set the space allowed to maximum, was that not the correct procedure to enable persistence? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: Yes, that is the correct procedure. But with persistence, programs installed by `apt` are not discarded on shutdown. I'd say something went wrong in how persistence was set up.

Comment: I mean, there's not much I could have messed up though right? I just made sure that the option to store changes was clicked and moved the slider, should I try redoing the disk creator?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to follow [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643080/how-to-create-a-live-system-on-usb-drive-with-persistent-changes-on-disk-hdd) with two small exceptions:

Don't delete the home directory and don't link to an external HDD (steps 4 & 5)

Then you'll have a fully working Ubuntu-on-a-stick…  **:-)**

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: How do I know if I have an SLC flash?

Comment: Do you have a brand and product number?  If not: what's the size and how much did you pay?