# Switch from casper-rw file to casper-rw partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in 16 GB USB drive. I am a newbie in the ubuntu world. I am trying to create a USB disk with 12 GB persistence storage. So that I can use it for the development purposes.

I have created this USB drive using `unetbootin`. I have selected `100 MB` persistence while creating the disk, because I wanted to switch to `casper-rw` ext2 partition which I created and having `12 GB` space. But, even after restarting and booting to windows and live-ubuntu more than 20 times with different settings and juggling between different tools, still unable to get that partition working.

I have tried `rufus`, `unetbootin`, and `linuxpendrive` tools for making persistent file storage system. But to enable partition, I have failed all the time. If I change the `txt.cfg` file from my windows, it ends up in Busybox dead screen without any error.

First, I partitioned my usb storage to 2 drives from windows 10 using EaseUS Partition Manager. 1 `fat32` of `2 GB` and 1 `ext2` with `casper-rw` label. Then Installed ubuntu using unetbootin with persistance settings to 100 MB. It works but doesn't use partition for persistence. When I check from the command: `df . -h` , it says I have /cow with 100 MB space. I tried to delete the file `casper-rw` from USB drive from fat32 partition from Windows and again booted from USB. But, it fails to boot and stuck to BusyBox Screen.

One article I followed:
https://askubuntu.com/a/438734/588390

I tried:

- As rufus doesn't provide direct option to enable persistence, I tried enabling it with linuxpendrive's Casper-RW creator tool (http://www.pendrivelinux.com/casper-rw-creator-make-a-persistent-file-from-windows/). Then deleted and/or renamed `casper-rw` file in the root usb. But didn't worked.
- Tried editing `txt.cfg` file and it ended up in dead Busybox screen with all the 3 tools.
- I also tried editing one cfg file inside `boot/grub` but also ended up in the Black Busybox dead screen.

What's going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You said " I have selected 100 MB persistence while creating the disk, because I wanted to switch to casper-rw ext2 partition which I created and having 12 GB space. " What is the difference between this 100 MB persistence and your 12GB casper-rw file?

Comment: Because, It was mentioned in many articles that first create with casper-rw file and then delete that file so it will use the casper-rw partition

Comment: You need to repoint your boot-loader menu (grub) to the new partition. (this is the advice that is generally not pointed out on casper-partition answers!) I managed to get this working recently with a Lubuntu 14.04 custom iso as described here ([http://askubuntu.com/a/878009/544376](http://askubuntu.com/a/878009/544376)). that's my answer to someone else's question where he was having a similar issue. My answer used other answers on that 'thread', so be sure to read the entire thread before you try again. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **mkusb** to create persistent live drive. It creates a **partition for persistence** by default and automatically. The picture shows the steps in the wizard interface to create a persistent live system with **mkusb version 12** alias **dus**.

[image]

See the following links for more details,

[How do I make a persistent live USB of Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768970/how-do-i-make-a-persistent-live-usb-of-ubuntu-16-04/856083#856083)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf)