# mkusb fails to make persistent USB

Tags: live-usb, persistence, mkusb

As per the advice in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899098/making-live-usb-with-persistant-storage/899100?noredirect=1#comment1409611_899100), I have attempted to use mkusb to make a persistent USB drive. However, it fails to do so (or any other function it has when pointed at that USB)

If it is relevant, I am running mkusb on Lubuntu an IBM T-42 Thinkpad with 1GB ram and an intel Centrio mobile processor (I had to force PAE on install). I am attempting to boot the liveUSB on a Dell Insperion all-in-one with Windows 8.

Console output of mkusb:

```
 mkusb-dus - Do USB Stuff 
mkusb-dus needs superuser permissions (sudo) for some tasks, in order to prepare and write to the target, a block device.
 dus 12.0.7 
live system or temporary superuser permissions
Drive that contains source file: /dev/sda
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/sda
cands=2

  4K

  4K
built-in device
sdb
SanDisk_Ultra
28.7G
usb
USB or memory card
p_target: target=/dev/28.7G
No device or bad device
p_clean:
live system or temporary superuser permissions
clean if necessary and return
 Press Enter to finish mkusb-dus
```

Comment: I will test in my IBM T-42 Thinkpad with a similar USB drive (a 32 GB Sandisk Extreme). Which version of Lubuntu is installed in your Thinkpad? I intend to install the same version in my Thinkpad.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 according to the OS section in system information. (I definatly have Lubuntu, not sure why it says Ubuntu)

Comment: OK, I will install it and try. (It will take some time, because the computer is old and slow...)

Comment: I can confirm that you have found a bug. I think it depends on some 'junk output' that confuses the listing of available drives, when there is a floppy drive. I'm testing a bugfix now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56439/discussion-between-sudodus-and-j-smith).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a debugging dialogue, the bug was found and squashed. The problem was some confusing data due to a floppy drive (a bug that only affects very old computers) in the function `p_list_drives` in the program `dus`:

```
grep -v zram --> grep -v -e zram -e ^fd
```

A new version can be installed via the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The current update (2017-04-02) installs mkusb version 12.0.9

**Edit:** After further testing (2017-04-03) this version is uploaded to the stable PPA, `ppa:mkusb/ppa` and can be installed via the following 'standard' commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```