# How to save files from a live usb boot to computer?

Tags: live-usb, persistence, mass-storage

Here's the scenario: I would like to use a live USB to boot up my computer sometimes and access large programs that I want to run in Ubuntu only. However, I only have access to an 8gb USB drive, and the programs I'm looking at are around 50gb and upwards. From my research, I think I have to set up persistence, but instead of saving files to my USB, I want to be able to save files to my computer without messing up my current operating system and whatnot. How do I do that?

EDIT: If I mount my hard drive, is there anything I have to do to make my programs install there, and how can I do it so that my OS settings are stored on the USB (So I can take it with me), and my large programs are still on my OS.

EDIT: Errors with `mkusb`

```
Drive that contains source file: /dev/sda
Live drive, that is booted from: /dev/sda
cands=2

 50G

 50G
built-in device
sdb
SanDisk_Cruzer_Glide
 7.5G
usb
USB or memory card
p_target: target=/dev/ 7.5G
No target device or bad target device
p_clean:
```

Comment: I often use NFS mounts (ie. network fs) even from 'live' media. I can `mount` wherever I want it; though smaller stuff I just save locally & `scp` to a server for storage  (SaMBa/cifs could be used also, so you don't have to use a local mounted hdd/persistence).  Note: 'live' uses memory for everything & installing large programs/updates can run a 'live' out of memory in my experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Persistent live with a `casper-rw` partition in the internal drive

- You can create a persistent live drive with mkusb according to the following links,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)
- Ubuntu will search for a file with the name **`casper-rw`** or a partition with the label **`casper-rw`**, and use the first one that it finds. So you can

  - remove or re-label the **`casper-rw`** partition on the USB pendrive (created by mkusb),
  - In Windows shrink the Windows partition (typically `C:`) and leave the freed drive space as 'unallocated'.
  - Boot live-only from the Ubuntu live drive, 'Try Ubuntu',

    - start `gparted` and

      - create a partition in the unallocated drive space and
      - in the partition create an `ext4` file system
      - set the label **`casper-rw`** on this partition
  - Now, when you reboot the Ubuntu live drive, you should be able to boot persistent live and it will use the **`casper-rw`** partition in the internal drive. It should be possible to install your large programs and they are stored (automatically) in the **`casper-rw`** partition in the internal drive.

### Test that it really works

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the **`casper-rw`** partition in the internal drive `/dev/sda` is 49 GiB, and it is used for persistence. The operating system is running from a [16 GB] USB pendrive `/dev/sdb`, where the automatically created `casper-rw` partition is re-labeled to `casper-off`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I guess I have to rename my usb pendrive from casper-rw and back each time I want to use it on a different computer.

Comment: It is enough to re-label the `casper-rw` partition in the USB pendrive. I tested that it really works with a Lubuntu system (and I will add a screenshot to the answer).

Comment: Also, do i have to partition the c drive in windows, or can i do it once i'm in ubuntu?

Comment: It is much safer to shrink the C: partition and the NTFS file system with Windows, and after that use Ubuntu to create a partition in it. 'Manage Windows file systems with Windows tools, and linux file systems with linux tools'.

Comment: I tried using mkusb, but I'm having the same problem as in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/899341/mkusb-fails-to-make-persistant-usb I'm also using a sandisk usb, but only with 7.5gb. I get the same errors for both live installation and persistant. I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: I will try to debug your problem. 1. Which version of Ubuntu are you running (the operating system, where you have installed mkusb)? 2. Which version of mkusb are you running? 2. What computer is it (brand name and model)? 4. Is there a floppy drive in the computer? If not, it is probably another problem with similar symptoms. 5. Please edit your original question to post the exact error output. Indent each line 4 spaces in order to render the output as 'code'.

Comment: 1. Ubuntu 17.10  2. Dus 12.2.9 3. Hp omen (through a virtual machine I'm accessing ubuntu with vmware workstation 12 4. The floppy drive is in the computer, but is mounted through the virtual machine. This might be the cause of the problem, in that case no worries, since I can just make one without partitioning.

Comment: I have not tested mkusb with vmware. (I have tested it with virtualbox, and it works.) Probably there is a problem with some drive specification in vmware, that I never had a chance to debug. Please try in another system and let me know if it works. If not, I can suggest alternatives ...

Comment: That's alright, I also have virtualbox, so I'll see if I can work it out there, but so far you've answered everything I wanted to know, so thank you so much.

Comment: I saw the error output (in the edited original question), and I agree, that it is very similar to the error in the link you show in a previous comment. (I am thinking of a questionmark: I tested in virtualbox with an earlier version of Ubuntu (not 17.10) and probably also and earlier version of virtualbox, but I run mkusb 'all the time' in 17.10 installed in bare metal ...). Good luck :-)

Comment: Actually, virtualbox managed to make the usb, but even after editting the bios it won't boot up ubuntu. So i am stuck with a regular, non persistent usb. As such, how to I make it automatically detect the internal casper partition I made? It seems like i have to mount it every time, and even then it just has my files but not my ubuntu settings.

Comment: @Led, Are you trying to boot a virtual machine from USB? Can you boot another computer from the USB drive made by mkusb? 1. Maybe you can use the **'Do It Yourself'** method described in the following links, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy ; 2. another alternative is to add the boot option **`persistent`** to your 'non-persistent USB'. See  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/sp

Answer (score 0):

You could probably mount the hard drive of the computer as it is.

To find what partitions you have on the system run
  sudo fdisk -l

Then mount the apropriate partition
  sudo mount /dev/device /mnt/mountpoint

You might need to specify type of the device. Use
  -t type
where type can be ntfs or other file formats supported by your live USB.

Comment: So if I mount the hard drive, are there any things I have to watch out for? Such as overwriting important files, or it will i be able to navigate files just like in windows, and when I boot up windows I can access those same files? Sorry about so many questions, I'm really new to linux so bear with me.

Comment: The windows disk will be a part of your ubuntu file system. As such it is possible to erase files, but it will not happen by itself or by just mounting the file system. Since you are running windows it will be necessary to use the falg -t ntfs to the mount command