# Persistence, casper-rw partition problems

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, persistence

I've been through numerous sites/forums/how-to's and still am baffled. What is causing the problem, I believe, is the casper-rw partition not being recognized at bootup. I have looked at few posts here and must say, it's rather confusing. So, what must be done to make the *casper-rw partition* be recognized at bootup? And, I still have to delete the casper-rw file in the O.S.? Running Xubuntu 18.3 live--2GB partition for O.S. and 1 GB for casper-rw(ext2) on a 16GB Lexar 2.0 pendrive. The link listed below gives a fairly accurate description of my problem:

*[Unable to boot Ubuntu Live USB Flash Drive with casper-rw persistent partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664577/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-live-usb-flash-drive-with-casper-rw-persistent-partition/878009#878009)*

Appreciated:
***Rick***

Comment: Currently syslinux type installers like UNetbootin, Rufus, Universal and Startup Disk Creator do not allow a persistent partition on the same drive, a persistent partition works OK as long as it is on a different drive.

Answer (score 2):

Currently syslinux type installers like **UNetbootin**, **Rufus**, **Universal** and **Startup Disk Creator** do not allow a persistent partition on the same drive, a persistent partition works OK as long as it is on a different drive.

**YUMI** can create multiple persistence files for multiple OS and uses grub4dos to make casper-rw files greater than 4GB.

Persistent partitions work great if used on a grub2 type persistent drive such as **mkusb** creates.

mkusb will create a flash drive with FAT boot partition, ISO9660 OS partition, ext2 casper-rw persistence partition and a NTFS data partition accessible to Linux and Windows. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Download mkusb to a ubuntu boot drive and use it to make your persistent drive.

Comment: You wrote "currently". Is this still true and if the limitation is no longer valid: starting with which version of the tools mentioned has the limitation become obsolete? Using unetbootin 681-1~bionic1 I have made a stick with ubuntostudio 20.04 with a partition casper-rw, formatted as ext2 and 11GiB big and apparently the stick was persistent. However my persistent pen drives did not work very stable and installing programs took very much time, also starting an shutting down the system.