# Installing iso files on ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

How can I install an iso file on a USB while I'm using a live Ubuntu OS?

I want to make a persistent USB drive with Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit on a USB in an iso file, I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 lts 64 bit live how can I install the 32 bit iso file on the USB?

And I can't use Unetbootin, it says: "E: Unable to locate package unetbootin"

Comment: boot the 32 bit image and choose the USB in the installer.

Comment: how do i boot the 32 bit iso image?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/USB%20Installation%20Media

Answer (score 2):

You can use Unetbootin to create a persistent USB drive as you can see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138356/how-do-i-get-a-live-usb-to-use-a-partition-for-persistence).

So what you should do next:

- Create two  partitions on your destination USB drive with gparted

  - First one should be FAT32 with at least 750MB in size.
  - Second will be the rest for example (label: casper-rw, filesystem: ext4)

    [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVyLL.png)
- Install Unetbootin:

  sudo apt-get install unetbootin

**Update:** ... or you can use the binaries from the [author's site](http://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html)

> To run these binaries, download them and run the command chmod +x 
>   ./unetbootin-linux, or go to Properties->Permissions and check "Execute"), then 
>   start the application by running ./unetbootin-linux

- Set it up as you can see on the image below

  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYQjd.png)
- Once everything is done, the final step is to delete the small casper-rw file created on the vfat partition you installed the LiveCD on, so that the large ext4 casper-rw partition is used instead. Mount this partition (here, sdb1), and delete /casper-rw.

Persistence (via the persistent kernel option) should already be set up if you used Unetbootin, so safely eject the USB and you're ready to go!

Armand

Comment: close but every package I try to install appears damaged

Comment: @user481452: Damaged? What does it say exactly? Unetbootin is in the main repository so type sudo apt-get install unetbootin 

I did it seconds ago and it worked great.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It sais "E: Unable to locate package unetbootin"

Comment: @user481452 I've updated my answer. With the binary method it works the same way but it does not need to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended tool would likely be startup disk creator.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: Tried it, didnt work for what i need it

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool to use is [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/).

It needs no installation and allows you even to download the iso in the application itself.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.