# Ubuntu on USB - partitioning

Tags: partitioning, usb

I am thinking of using a bootable USB drive for Ubuntu, but I have a quick question about partitioning the drive. I am using a 32GB flash drive. How much should I partition the drive, and what would be the purpose of partitioning it? For example, why not just leave the drive un-partitioned and use Ubuntu as such? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't fully understand what you need, but,
Ubuntu on USB flash drives can be used in two kinds:

1. As a live-bootable media.
2. Full Installation media.

**#1** is the one, which you create using [startup-disk-creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/) or [UnetBootIn](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unetbootin/), and changes you make in a session are only confined to the size of persistent file you specify at the time of creation of the bootable usb drive. 
To know how to create partition on the installation media follow [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138356/how-do-i-get-a-live-usb-to-use-a-partition-for-persistence)
 **#2** is, what you get when you install ubuntu using a live-cd or live-usb to another usb drive. Here you can partition your usb drive just like you would do on another on-board hard drives.