# Is Persistence too small for installing 16.04?

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, live-usb, persistence

While I tried again to install 16.04 on pre-formatted LUKS + lvm2,

- I created an USB(3) live stick (with usb-creator-gtk, from 14.04).
- There I choosed a permanence of 4 GiB, for preserving my work and tools for the coming installations.
- But now I see on the mounted stick a folder "casper" with a size of about 1,5 GiB, which is about the size of the 16.04 image.

  Now the experience of my last try tells me that, on the live system
- The root file system "/" was  on the device "cow", with the size of 1,5 GiB, 500 MiB left, which were uses up in the middle of the first step of the installation, forcing me to break up.
- [**although:** I see there the file /media//B6A3-7DB8/casper/filesystem.size, containing the number 4186521600 (bytes?) What is *that* for?]

(Referring to usb-creator-gtk) I think that:

- **The persistence sizing up to 4 GiB does not do its job.**
- The persistency is not made for data of substantial size (while it it may  work, say for a couple of conf files).

Are my above statements right?

I know of questions like [Persistence On Partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138356/how-do-i-get-a-live-usb-to-use-a-partition-for-persistence?lq=1%22Persistence%20On%20Partition%22) or [Live media For UEFI Only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media?lq=1%22Live%20Media%20UEFI%20Only%22), but I would like the decleared tools for Ubuntu Starters *to do* what they promise first.

Comment: I have tried three times to install 16.04 with persistence, getting "no space left on device", persistently!. I then installed  **without**  persistence, successfully, and fast enough. The next time I will try Persistence On Partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu give **mkusb** a try.

It will make an install with persistence size limited only by the size of the USB drive. It will leave any leftover space formatted NTFS, accessible to both Linux and Windows.

You can run it from Live CD or USB.

The casper folder is where they keep the SquashFS file, it is the compressed file system that runs the O/S, it is read only.